# Image and text in same Css Grid area

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a 4x11 grid and I am trying to place an image and caption next to it within the same area. Currently, the image is sitting above the text, rather than to the left in line with it:

```
<div class="Time">
  <figure class = "Time-icon">
    <img src="/images/time.png" alt="time icon" width= "20%" height= "20%">
  </figure>
  <h2>Time</h2>
</div>
```

```
.time { 
  grid-area: 10 / 3 / 12 / 4; 
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 85px;
} 

.time-icon{
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
```

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

How would I go about making the icon sit nicely to the left inline with the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use this `css`.

```
.time {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.time-icon {
    margin: 0 8px 0 0;
    width: 20%;
    height: 20%;
}
.time-icon img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="time">
    <figure class = "time-icon">
        <img src="/images/time.png" alt="time icon">
    </figure>
    <h2>Time</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: It works but leaves a very large gap between the two items. How would i shrink that?

Comment: I will change my answer.

Comment: this has changed the image size not the gap between them unfortunately

Comment: I understand. I will change again.

Answer (score 0):

you should use for this display flex, not float left.

```css
.container{
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="hec.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg/512px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png" width="60px" height="60px" alt="logo">
        <h2>This is a  logo!</h2>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the flex works as following George's method, however by itself it has no affect on the text or the image